# Tweaking scrollbar behavior in Gtk3 (gtk-primary-button-warps-slider)

Tags: themes, gtk3, scrollbar

I am trying to create a theme for Xubuntu 17.04 ([see/test here](http://xfce-evolution.sourceforge.net)) that looks as consistent as possible across Gtk2, Gtk3, Qt4, Qt5, and wxWidgets applications (i personally find Adwaita unusable, no scrollbar buttons, scrollbars don't show up in OpenOffice, annoyingly inconsistent looks on Qt menus and Qt5.7+ fusion apps, distracting backdrop shading only in Gtk3 apps, etc). I managed to make some progress in this direction (with the menu colors, scrollbars, etc) and eventually ran into the Gtk3 scrollbar behavior wherein left-clicking on the scrollbar positions the document to the clicked position instead of going one page up or down.

I googled for a couple of days and found that i can create a "settings.ini" file in my theme's gtk-3.0 folder containing:

```
[Settings]
gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false
```

Now, this does the trick w/ respect to reverting to the old scrollbar behavior  (page up/down on scrollbar left-click), but the problem is that **the auto-repeat rate is way too slow** (much slower than in Gtk-2)

So my question is: **is there a way to set the page-up/down scroll auto-repeat rate in Gtk-3** when keeping pressed the left mouse button on the scrollbar?